# Multidimensional data lookup

Tags: data-structures

I have a collection of tuples of N values. A value may be a wildcard (matches any value), or a concrete value. What would be the best way to lookup all tuples in the collection matching a specific tuple without scanning the entire collection and testing items one by one?

E.g. `1.2.3` matches `1.*.3` and `*.*.3`, but not `1.2.4` or `*.2.4`.

What data structure am I looking for here?

Comment: why does 1.2.3 != 1.2.3?

Comment: Something like a Tree might work, wouldn't it? Every leaf would be a tuple and every successive root would be the mutually common characters between two tuples ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to implement this.  Here's how I would construct the trie:

The data structure would look like:

```
Trie{
  Integer value
  Map<Integer, Trie> tries
}
```

To insert:

```
insert(tuple, trie){
  curTrie = trie
  foreach( number in tuple){
    nextTrie = curTrie.getTrie(number)
    //add the number to the trie if it isn't in there
    if(nextTrie == null){
      newTrie = new Trie(number)
      curTrie.setTrie(number, newTrie)          
    }
    curTrie = curTrie.getTrie(number)
  }
}
```

To get all the tuples:

```
getTuples(tuple, trie){
  if(head(tuple) == "*"){
    allTuples = {}
    forEach(subTrie in trie){
      allTuples.union(getTuples(restOf(tuple), subTrie))
      forEach(partialTuple in allTuples){
        partialTuple = head(tuple)+partialTuple
      }
    }
    return allTuples
  }
  if(tuple == null)
    return {trie.value}

  if(trie.getTrie(head(tuple)) == null)
    raise error because tuple does not exist
  allTuples = {}
  allTuples.union(getTuples(restOf(tuple), trie.getTrie(head(tuple))
  forEach(partialTuple in allTuples){
    partialTuple = head(tuple)+partialTuple
  }
  return allTuples
}
```